# JavaScript function working in IE not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, block

I am facing problem while enabling & disabling the `div` block in web page. I need to display `dvMessage` block in non-working hours and `dvChat` in working hours.

For this I have written a code CheckTime as follows:

```
function CheckTime() {          
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var time = hours + ":" + minutes
    var isweekend = currentTime.getDay();
    if ((time >= "20:00" && time <= "8:00")) {
        document.getElementById("dvMessage").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("dvChat").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("dvMessage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dvChat").style.display = "block";
        //End
    }
}
```

Calling this function at `body onload="CheckTime();` `div id="dvChat"` and `div id="dvMessage" style="display: none;" class="message"`

But this function works in IE but not in chrome. Is there anything else I need to do for Crome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hamster !

Comment: where have to defined currentTime?

Comment: You should [check your browser's console for error messages](http://help.gawker.com/customer/portal/articles/1569034-how-do-i-open-my-browser-s-javascript-console-) and then [edit] your question to include any errors.

Comment: currentTime is undefined. But after fix it workd fine http://jsbin.com/pexekuhoxu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: And please don't forget to add the missing semicolons ';'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It works after currentTime is defined and adding missing Semicolons.

```
 function CheckTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var time = hours + ":" + minutes;
    var isweekend = currentTime.getDay();
    if ((time >= "20:00" && time <= "9:00")) {
        document.getElementById("dvMessage").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("dvChat").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("dvMessage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dvChat").style.display = "block";
        //End
    }
}
```